# About some equivalent cases

Tags: logic

I have two equivalent cases:

**Case A**: There exist $k≥2$ such that $f(u_{k})=0$ 
$$⇔$$
**Case B**: There exist $k≥2$ we have $-1< t_{k}<1$

Here $f, u_{k},t_{k}$ are all given quantities.

We notice the following:

**Case A** is not true for all $j$.
It is unkonwn if there exist infinitely many $k$ verifying **Case A**

For **Case B**

**Case B** is true for all $j>1$. So there exist infinitely many $j$ verifying **Case B**.

I am asking about this equivalence case:

**Case C**: There exist infinitely many $j$ verifying **Case B**
$$⇔$$

**Case D**: There exist infinitely many $j$ verifying **Case A**

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @wece: It is OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment removed: It is now an Answer**

Consider the following

- $f(u_3)=0$ and $f(u_i)=1$ otherwise
- $t_k=0$ for all k

Case A is equivalent to case B since both are true.
However A hold only for a single $k$ and B for all k